# Python: Flask return internal server error with two routes

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I need two inputs that can access the same database, using Stock and Stockcode.
However, it returns internal server error

My code is as below:

```
@app.route('/NYSE/<Stock>', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/NYSE/<Stockcode>', methods=['GET'])
def NYSEstock(Stock,Stockcode):
    try:
        call = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM NYSE WHERE (Stockcode LIKE :param or Stock LIKE :param1)",{"param":Stockcode,"param1":Stock})
        c = call.fetchall()
        c1 = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in c]
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Stock': c1})
```

My data in MySQL is as below:

```
{
  "Stock": [
    {
      "index": 189,
      "Stock": "IBM",
      "Stockcode": "4350",
      "MACD": "No",
      "STOCH": "No",
      "RSI": "No",
}]
```

I expect the route `/NYSE/IBM` and `/NYSE/4350` both able to access the data. /NYSE will contains many stocks but with `/NYSE/<Stock>` or `/NYSE/<Stockcode`>, we will able to find the specific stock.

Separate it to two will able to solve the problem, but I prefer to have only one def

```
@app.route('/NYSE/<Stock>', methods=['GET'])
def NYSEstock(Stock):
    try:
        call = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM NYSE WHERE (Stock LIKE :param )",{"param":Stock})
        c = call.fetchall()
        c1 = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in c]
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Stock': c1})

@app.route('/NYSEstockcode/<Stockcode>', methods=['GET'])
def NYSEstockcode(Stock):
    try:
        call = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM NYSE WHERE (Stockcode LIKE :param )",{"param":Stockcode})
        c = call.fetchall()
        c1 = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in c]
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Stock': c1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is NYSEstock function, it's must be accepted one parameter. because app.route decorator just adds one rule, the router just has one parameter, you can refer to below code:

```
@app.route('/NYSE/<stock_or_id>', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/NYSE/<stock_or_id>', methods=['GET'])
def NYSEstock(stock_or_id):
    try:
        call = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM NYSE WHERE (Stockcode LIKE :param or Stock LIKE :param1)",{"param":stock_or_id,"param1":stock_or_id})
        c = call.fetchall()
        c1 = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in c]
    except Exception:
       return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
   #return "hihi"
   return jsonify({'Stock': c1})
```